# arrayindexoutofboundsexception while using LWUIT ImageDownloadService

Tags: lwuit, nokia-s40

I am using Nokia-Lwuit for my project,While using the `ImageDownloadService`and I am getting a  uncaught `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` while the thread is trying to update the `Label` with the downloaded image .
This is because the urls returned in the response point to no image, but I am not able to fix it or catch it.I have tried overriding many methods such as the `handleErrorResponseCode`,`handleException`,`handleIOException` with no success.

Kindly help me out to catch this exception or fix it some how.

With Regards,
Ashwin

Comment: this is partly why i don't use lwuit for IO, cause i couldn't catch exceptions, i hope there is a work around, but i suggest you use a custom solution.

Answer (score 2):

I develop in Lwuit.
I build a class that try to get images from internet. Whem i develop to blackberry i get problem likes you, when i create image  its failed on image length.

This occurs because I use in METHOD POST and sometimes in some case that occurs to problem in header request(this depends if you need to send parameters) and to return of response status 400 or 411.

Comment: was your problem solved because i am facing the same problem in mobile, "411 lenght required" but works perfectly in simulator.